# Vimium concept for Windows/Linux desktop

Tags: user-interface, keyboard, operating-system, controls, ui-automation

lately I discovered this awesome chrome extension [vimium](https://vimium.github.io/) and really love the idea to control GUI (in this case chrome) with some sort of popups if shortcuts not available or unknown.

I searched for while but couldn't find any general tool or OS which supports such kind of navigation with Keyboard in GUI application.

I know that at least for Windows automation for GUI applications is possible but couldn't find any existing project, so I tried it myself but it didn't worked well in the end.

My Question: Is there ANY similar program/project/OS to vimium available but in a more general way, so that I can control the whole desktop (with help from popups/modals) with my Keyboard?

Thanks

Comment: Here  for linux:
https://github.com/phil294/vimium-everywhere
Only for x11, no wayland yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used a combination of following  two programs to get semi Vimium-like functionality in Windows.

**Hunt-and-Peck** - 
https://github.com/zsims/hunt-and-peck
This works like vimium on the active window. Uses "ALT+;" as the trigger. Doesn't work in all programs. (Only supports UI Automation Elements with "invoke" patterns) I use it mostly in File Explorer and to trigger Chrome Browser Extensions or other chrome elements outside the active page (that can't be accessed with vimium).

**FastWindowSwitcher**
https://github.com/JochenBaier/fastwindowswitcher
I find this to be quicker than using ALT+TAB or WIN+TAB to quickly switch to another active window.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows, I use **Fluent Search**: https://www.fluentsearch.net/
[Demo video at Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF1-8OrLJYQ&list=PL-N25EGaajJIWGl43CJbMI6BpTa54R0nt&index=2)

For macOS, **Vimac** works very similarly to Vimium: https://vimacapp.com/

Linux has **keynav**, which is not exactly the same, but also works great:
https://github.com/jordansissel/keynav

That said, it's X11 only. I actually ended up in this Stack Overflow question after searching for a keynav alternative, as I'm currently using Wayland.